# Number of unique pairs within one column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am having a little problem with producing statistics for my dataframe in pandas. My dataframe looks like this (I omit the index):

```
id    type  
1      A
2      B
3      A
1      B
3      B
2      C
4      B
4      C
```

What is important, each `id` has two `type` values assigned, as can be seen from the example above. I want to count all `type` combinations occurrences (so count number of unique `id` with given `type` combination), so I want to get such a dataframe:

```
type    count
A, B      2
A, C      0
B, C      2
```

I tried using `groupby` in many ways, but in vain. I can do this kind of 'count' using `for-loop` and a number of lines of code, but I believe there has to be elegant and proper (in python terms) solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: So you're trying to create combinations of size 2 from all the `type`s and count how many of these there are grouped by id? Am I understanding this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` + `apply` with `value_counts`:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combs(types):
    return pd.Series(list(combinations(sorted(types), 2)))

res = df.groupby('id')['type'].apply(combs).value_counts()

print(res)

(A, B)    2
(B, C)    2
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 5):

#### `pd.value_counts` and `itertools.combinations`

```
from itertools import combinations

pd.value_counts(
    [(x, y) for _, d in df.groupby('id') for x, y in combinations(d.type, 2)]
)

(A, B)    2
(B, C)    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Counter`, `groupby` and the default constructor

```
from collections import Counter
>>> pd.DataFrame(Counter([tuple(v.type.values) for _,v in df.groupby('id')]), index=['Count']).T

        Count
A   B   2
B   C   2
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using `unique`, notice only good for two unique value within one id

```
df.groupby('id').type.unique().apply(tuple).value_counts()
Out[202]: 
(A, B)    2
(B, C)    2
Name: type, dtype: int64
```