# count the number of unique combinations in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, combinations

I am having trouble (brain block) producing some simple summary statistics for my data.

What I would like to do is to count the number of co-occurring "code" values across all "id"s. The data looks like:

```
id    code  
1      A
2      A
2      B
3      A
3      B
4      A
5      A
5      C
6      A
6      B
6      C
```

So the output would look like this table. Or perhaps by adding a factorized column on the raw data "combo-id" for each unique combination.

```
Combo    Count    combo-id
(A)      2        1
(A,B)    2        2
(A,C)    1        3
(A,B,C)  1        4
```

[Here is a similar QA, but looking at unique pairs only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53159144/number-of-unique-pairs-within-one-column-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `tuple`s per groups and then get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
s = df.groupby('id')['code'].apply(tuple).rename('Combo')
#if duplicates don't matter, thank you @cripcate
#s = df.groupby('id')['code'].apply(set).rename('Combo')
df1 = s.groupby(s).size().reset_index(name='Count')
print (df1)
       Combo  Count
0       (A,)      2
1     (A, B)      2
2  (A, B, C)      1
3     (A, C)      1
```

Comment: +1 for this sleek (more or less) one-liner. You can also use `set(x)` instead of `tuple(x)`  if duplicates don't matter

Answer (score -2):

Try adding .unique()

> Series.unique()[source]
>
> ```
> Return unique values of Series object.
>
> Uniques are returned in order of appearance. Hash table-based unique, therefore does NOT sort.
> ```

[More here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)